# How to make WCSession reachable when the watchOS app is running in background with HKWorkoutSession

Tags: ios, watchkit, watchos, wcsession

My watchOS app uses workout API in order to stay running while the app goes to background. The issue is that `WCSession` becomes unreachable when the app is in background. However, I'm able to run my code and on some condition, it needs to send a message to the iPhone counterpart app.

The specifics of the app require that user doesn't have to interact with it - if there is a timeout, the watch app should send the message to the phone automatically.

Is this possible to achieve? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `handle(_ backgroundTasks: Set<WKRefreshBackgroundTask>)` method is what you're looking for. [Documentation Link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkextensiondelegate/1650877-handle)

Without seeing your code I can't be sure what your current progress is, but I have used this method to update watchOS Complications in the background as the user's location changes.

```
func handle(_ backgroundTasks: Set<WKRefreshBackgroundTask>) {
    for task in backgroundTasks {
        if WKExtension.shared().applicationState == .background {
            // Do your background work here.
            if let watchComplication = task as? WKWatchConnectivityRefreshBackgroundTask {
                pendingConnectivityTasks.append(watchComplication)
            }
        }
        task.setTaskCompletedWithSnapshot(true)
    }
    completePendingConnectivityTasksIfNeeded()
}
```

As a side note I will add if your app is not an actual workout app, it will get rejected during App Review for using a HealthKit workout session.

Comment: These messages need to be sent pretty frequently in the background. Do you suggest that I need to start a background task each time before sending such messages?

Comment: Background execution time is controlled and can be throttled or killed by watchOS. If you have a lot of data to send I'd try batching the data in an array or collection type of some sort. Then send those collections during the background session. Halfway down this page is where this background budgeting is discussed. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/background_execution/using_background_tasks

Comment: Then it wouldn't cut it. I need the app to be able to communicate with the phone counterpart at any time while running in background for indefinite amount of time.